# Borrowing self as mutable and a member of self not possible?

Tags: rust

```
struct State {
    x: i32
}

trait A {
    fn a(&mut self, b: &i32);
}

impl A for State {
    fn a(&mut self, b: &i32) {
        
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = State{x: 0};
    a.a(&a.x);
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `a` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 |     a.a(&a.x);
   |     ^^-^----^
   |     | | |
   |     | | immutable borrow occurs here
   |     | immutable borrow later used by call
   |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

It looks like the error talks about borrowing `self`, but I'm borrowing self only once, the second `b` should be a **borrow of a member of the struct**.

When I borrow a member of the struct, does Rust borrow the struct entirely?

I took a read at https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html but it says that it's possible to borrow just an element of the struct as long as it's not a slice.

Comment: "When I borrow a member of the struct, does Rust borrow the struct entirely?" Yes. This means the `a` method could hypothetically get a mutable reference to `x`, which would alias the reference you created with `&a.x`.

Comment: It is possible to borrow `&mut a.y` and `&a.x` at the same time, so `&a.x` borrows only a part of `a`, `&mut a.y` another part, and `(&mut a).a()` the whole struct. The conflict originates from `&a.x` and `&mut a` overlapping. So the correct answer is not "Yes", but your explanation is not wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call your `A::a` method, it borrows a whole variable it implemented for. So you can't have immutable references to the same object (or it's content) at the same time.

```rust
struct State {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

trait A {
    fn a(&mut self, b: &i32); // borrow a whole `Self` always
}

impl A for State {
    fn a(&mut self, b: &i32) {
        // consider next code
        self.x *= 2 + *b;
        // if you provide `b` as `&a.x`, then it becomes unclear what result should be
    } // borrow a whole `Self` always
}

fn swap(first: &mut i32, second: &mut i32) {} // borrow only provided `i32`s

fn main() {
    let mut a = State{x: 0, y: 0};
    // a.a(&a.x); // you can't, as long as `a.a` borrows whole `State` 
    swap(&mut a.x, &mut a.y); // but you can borrow partially if the parts are separate
}
```